# How to Exclude Specific Lambdas When Deploying Serverless Applications?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I only use some lambdas in my local development environment. However, they are in the same `serverless.yml` file as the other lambdas that I use in both development and production environments.

I have looked in the documentation but could not find any information on whether it is possible to specify a parameter or something else to indicate that certain lambdas should not be deployed when running `sls deploy`.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `serverless-plugin-ifelse` plugin.

the 'If' condition can range , but , example.
assuming your function name is `func3`

```
plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-ifelse
    
custom:
  serverlessIfElse:
      - If: '"${self:custom.currentStage}" != "local"'
        Exclude:
          - functions.func3
```